# insert bash script output in vim file

Tags: image, vim

I'm writing markdown in Vim and using this shortcut to set correct markdown image syntax:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :s/.*/![](\0)/ <CR>
```

when pressing `,p`, `/path/to/image/img.jpg` (in my vim text file) becomes

```
![](/path/to/image/img.jpg)
```

But I want to add after that this `{ width = *variable*% }`, like this

```
![](img.jpg){ width = *variable*% }
```

I made this little bash script (`img.sh`) that gives me the variable according to the image size:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$(identify -format '%h' $1)

echo "scale=3; 300 * (100/$VAR)" | bc
```

If I do this in vim `:r !img.sh /path/to/image/img.jpg` I get a number in this case 32

I would want to launch this script with the shortcut above, I tried this:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :s/.*/![](\0){ width=/ <CR> :r !img.sh /path/to/image/img.jpg <CR> % }
```

I want you to help me to find a way to not type path to image to execute the script. Path to image is already written in the text if i could find a way to indicate to vim to place it in the shortcut after img.sh it would be great !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Vimscript expression on the replacement side of your `:s` command, that way you can refer to the text in the match (which is the path to the image) using [`submatch(0)`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29). You can use an expression on the replacement of a `:s` by beginning it with `\=`, see [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) for more details.

Using a replacement expression, you can also use the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function to call the external command, instead of using a separate `:r !...` command to read its output into the current buffer.

Putting it all together:

```
:s/.*/\='![]('.submatch(0).']{ width='.trim(system('img.sh '.submatch(0))).' }'/
```

Or to add a mapping to it:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :s/.*/\='![]('.submatch(0).']{ width='.trim(system('img.sh '.submatch(0))).' }'/<CR>
```

(NOTE: You might also want to add a `:noh` command to the end of your mapping, otherwise it will keep highlighting the search for `.*` which matches everything.)

```
nnoremap <leader>p :s/.*/\='![]('.submatch(0).']{ width='.trim(system('img.sh '.submatch(0))).' }'/\|noh<CR>
```